# Removing elements in layout breaks layout

Tags: html, css

When I remove the commented sections from the following code, it breaks the whole layout. This is bizarre, since the div and table that get commented out shouldn't affect the layout as a whole. Why is this happening?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Packard Carburetors </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div id="header">
    <h1 id="banner">Packard Carburetors</h1>
</div><!--Header-->

<div id="navbar" class="green">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li>PACKARD
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li>-1930 Speedster</li>
                <li>-1929-31 Super 8</li>
                <li>-Late 1931-32 Super 8</li>
                <li>-1929-31 Standard 8</li>
                <li>-Late 1931-32 Standard 8</li>
                <li>-Rare Parts</li>
                <li class="last">-745 Parts</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>CADILLAC
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li>-1932-33 V12 & V16</li>
                <li class="last">-1934-1937 V12 & V16</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>SHOPPING CART</li>
        <li>CHECK OUT</li>
        <li>CONTACT US</li>
    </ul><!--Navigation-->

    <img id="#navbar-logo" src="img/logo.png">
    <p id="nav-phone" class="black center bold">775.842.4282</p>
    <p class="black center nav-small bold">packardcarbs@gmail.com</p>
    <p class="black center nav-small bold">Sparks, NV USA</p>
</div><!--Navbar-->

<div id="content">

    <h1 class="home-banner green center bold">All Packard Carburetors 1929-'32</h1>
    <h2 class="home-banner green center bold">1930 Speedster <span class="black">|</span> 1929-32 Super 8 <span class="black">|</span> 1929-32 Standard 8</h2>
    <hr>
    <h1 class="home-banner green center bold">Cadillac Carburetors</h1>
    <h2 class="home-banner green center bold">1932 - 1937 V-12 & V-16</h2>

    <img id="detroit-lubricator" src="img./detroit-lubricator.png">

    <div id="middle-column">
        <ul id="feature-list-home">
            <li>Silicone Bronze Investment Casting</li>
            <li>Precision CNC Brass Machine Parts</li>
            <li>Viton-Tipped Needles</li>
            <li>Current Design
                <ul id="sub-feature-list-home">
                    <li>-Needle Seats</li>
                    <li>-Pressure Valves</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Authentic Polished Brass Components</li>
            <li>Gasoline and Ethanol Proof Exterior Coating</li>
            <li>Exact Size as Original</li>
        </ul>

        <!--<img id="middle-bar-spacer" src="img/divider-bar.png">

        <div id="box-and-copy">
            <img id="boxes" src="img/packard-boxes.png">

            <p class="bold">All Components In-Stock!</p>
            <p>Your Carburetor will be professionally assembled, engine tested and shipped quickly worldwide.</p>
        </div><!-- Box and copy -->

    </div><!--Middle Column -->

    <div id="right-column">
        <!--<table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/carb-1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="img/carb-1.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1930 Speedster</td>
                <td>1929-1931 Super 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/carb-3.png"></td>
                <td><img src="img/carb-4.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1932 Super 8</td>
                <td>1929-1931 Standard 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/box.png"></td>
                <td><img src="img/carb-5.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>1932 Standard 8</td>
            </tr>
        </table>-->
    </div> <!--Right Column-->
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <img class="bottom-spacer" src="img/spacer-bottom.png">

</div><!--Content-->

</div><!--Wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*General styles*/

.wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url('../img/body-bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;

}

#banner {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 940px;
    height: 201;
    background-image: url('../img/banner.png');
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/* Nav Stuff */

#navbar {
    width: 190px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.33em;
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 10px;
    float: left;
}

#navigation li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.sub-nav{
    font-size: .87em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}

#navigation li ul.sub-nav li.last {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#nav-phone {
    font-size: 1.19em;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.nav-small {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Middle Column */
#middle-column{
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
}

#feature-list-home {
    list-style-image: url('../img/bullet.png');
    font-size: 1.17em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#feature-list-home li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#sub-feature-list-home {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#sub-feature-list-home li {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#middle-bar-spacer {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#boxes {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#box-and-copy {
    font-size: 1.33em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Home Page Right Column */

#right-column {
    float: left;
    width: 420px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right-column table {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 3em;
}

#right-column table td {
    width:210px;
}

/* Home Content Banner Stuff */

.home-banner {
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

#detroit-lubricator {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Footer */
.bottom-spacer {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

/* OOCSS properties */

.green{
    color: #117041;
}

.black{
    color: #000000;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I tried this in JSFiddle, and the table and div didn't break anything. It might be your reset.css that's causing the trouble?

Comment: It's Eric Meyer's reset. I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox. This is really confusing me. I don't know why this is breaking.

Comment: @JoshInfiesto: Show your html after removing the commented sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by something in the nav-bar overflowing and breaking the layout. It resolved when the nav was set to overflow:hidden.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to not closing the opening comment tag of `img`

```
<!--<img id="middle-bar-spacer" src="img/divider-bar.png">
```

Comment: The comment is closed by the `Box and copy -->` and shouldn't affect the layout of the page.